# Marshal [in] reference without ref

Tags: c#, .net, com, marshalling, com-interop

Some functions, especially in COM interfaces, expose a *REFIID* parameter that is used to specify the type of the interface the methods should return. Here's such an example method:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", PreserveSig=false)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
static extern object SHBindToObject(IShellFolder psf, IntPtr pidl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]object pbc, [In]ref Guid riid);
```

The fourth parameter is input-only, and should not be changed by [*SHBindToObject*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so by C# conventions, it makes no sense passing it as a reference (aside from performance). I can't recall it clearly, but I remember that there should be some custom attribute or something that is designated for this case, to tell the marshaller that it should be really marshalled as if it were `ref Guid`, while it is specified without `ref` in the signature.

I looked for attributes in the *System.Runtime.InteropServices* names, fields on *MarshalAsAttribute*, and in the *UnmanagedType* enum, but without success.

Does there happen to be something similar, or is my memory incorrect? Is it good using such a thing in this case?

Comment: It is a very common practice to pass structs by reference in C and C++ code if the structure is large.  It avoids having the compiler create a copy of it, that gets expensive on large structs.  A good idea in C# as well, albeit that declaring large structs in C# is well known to be unwise.  Ideally such an argument uses the `const` qualifier but support for it is spotty.  Like it is in C#.  Using `ref Guid` is just fine and avoids the marshaller from having to create a copy.  You might be asking this to avoid wrangling the Guid so it can be passed with ref, that is not necessary since C# v4.

Comment: Starting with C# 7.2, you can use the `in` parameter modifier for an even simpler declaration.

`... pbc, in Guid riid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam_nathan/2003/04/23/the-confusing-unmanagedtype-lpstruct-marshaling-directive/):

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
static extern object SHBindToObject(
    IShellFolder psf,
    IntPtr pidl, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pbc,  
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);
```

Comment: Ah, of course. The MSDN documentation is severely lacking the appropriate information about this value. This also works well for COM methods, though I hoped other types than Guid could be used.

Comment: Well, it turns out you don't have to specify `ref` when calling methods in a COM imported interface. That's not what I would expect.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - Microsoft has simplified a lot of things with COM interop starting with .NET 4 (dynamic keyword for IDispatch calls, auto ref parameters, optional parameters, etc.). One reason was to ease Office Automation, for example Word methods had dozens of optional ref parameters and they were not super practical from .NET...